# How to write a conditional statement that refers to a certain index in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I want to code a statement that checks to see if a certain number is in an index of my list and then perform some task if it is and then pop this item from the list but i cant seem to find any solid info on this specific task. The code below does not work, but this is essentially what I'm trying to do. I believe that the error is in line 6 (`if item[2] ==3:`):

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Sample code:

```
x = [1,2,3]

for item in self.x:
      if item[2] == 3:
        print "working"
      else:
        print "not working"
```

Comment: `item` is one of the elements of your list, so `1`, then `2`, then `3`. I'm not sure I follow what you want to do here; did you want to see if `item == 3` perhaps?

Comment: yeah i want to look at an index i specify in the list and see if its equal to some number an item at index two in this case.

Comment: That'd be `self.x[2]`, not `item[2]`, but that'd be pointless to test in a loop.

Comment: Always show full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list.index() to find the item in the list, do your work then delete the indexed item:

```
x = [1,2,3]
try:
    index = x.index(3)    # find 3 or raise exception
    print "found"         # do your work
    del x[index]          # 'pop' (well, delete) 3
except ValueError:
    print "not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is iterating over each item in `x`.  Each integer is referenced via `item`.  Therefore, you are checking this: `if 3[2] == 3` which is a type error.

You can do the check outside of a for loop:

```
if x[2] == 3:
    print "working"
else:
    print "not working"
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` is the variable that the element from `x` is being stored in; you don't need to subscript anything.

```
x = [1,2,3]

for item in self.x:
      if item == 3:
        print "working"
      else:
        print "not working"
```